# Flexbox not appearing in mobile view

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to use flex box for mobile view but it does not seem to work for a specific box(the title flexbox works fine but the labels flex doesnt show).  Also, I have divs inside the labels flexbox as child elements

```css
@media screen and (max-width:450px) {
  .title {
    display: flex;
  }
  .click {
    display: none;
  }
  .name {
    display: flex;
    font-size: 50px;
  }
  .labels {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: aliceblue;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="labels">
  <div class="port social">Social</div>
  <div class="port bio">Bio</div>
  <div class="port web">Website</div>
  <div class="fancybox fancyboxy-iframe port resume" href="image/Weldons%20resume%20final.pdf" data-fancybox="gallery">Resume</div>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/ew39020/pen/MmEmyZ

Comment: do you have a codepen of this?

Comment: can you share a plunkr solution , so that we can take a look

Comment: do you code the whole thing like this in your post-question? if yes, its because the code structure is wrong and you should put the css up to your `<head>` tag and wrapped it with `<style> </style>`...

Comment: i just put in a link.  It works just not when I shrink my browser to mobile size

Comment: @iMarkDesigns Its in the head I update a codepen in the question.  It works but not in mobile view

Comment: There was a spelling mistake in the **.lables** class :  diplay: flex. Change it to display:flex and it will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I found two problems:

1. In Codepen CSS, row 19: you have `diplay` instead of `display`
2. In your snippet here: Media queries seem not to work here, because result is too wide.

And if you want elements to have equal width, just add `flex: 1` to them.

```css
  .title {
    display: flex;
  }
  .click {
    display: none;
  }
  .name {
    display: flex;
    font-size: 50px;
  }
  .labels {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: aliceblue;
  }
  .labels > * {
    flex: 1;
  }
```

```html
<div class="labels">
  <div class="port social">Social</div>
  <div class="port bio">Bio</div>
  <div class="port web">Website</div>
  <div class="fancybox fancyboxy-iframe port resume" href="image/Weldons%20resume%20final.pdf" data-fancybox="gallery">Resume</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your CodePen code, you misspelled the `display` property under `labels`:

```
.labels{
  diplay:flex; /* missing the `s` */
  width:100%;
  background:blue;
}
```

When I corrected this, the `flexbox` works. I also added a media query condition to test this under a smaller screen, and it worked.